# Writing an own swt widget - how to get current colors, gradients and other style data chosen by the OS?

Tags: widget, operating-system, styles, swt

I am writing an own swt widget.
Now I am ready with the functionality an trying to style the widget.

What is the default strategy to get the actual colors/styles, which are currently chosen by the OS?

How can I mimic the OS Style in my own widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all the predefined colors of SWT using the following:

```
Color color = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
```

Of course this holds for all the colors defined as `SWT.COLOR_*`.

The OS's default list background color can be accessed via:

```
SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND
```

As for the mimic question:

As long as you don't extend one of the default widgets, this will be quite hard to achieve. Please add some more detail to your question.

Comment: I thought, that maybe there is a default colorset, which is used by the OS widgets. Like lightblue for default WidgetBG in Windows... This is waht I men by mimic the OS

Comment: @Skip No, there isn't. You will have to get the colors from the widgets, i.e. if you want the light blue from windows, `SWT.COLOR_LIST_BACKGROUND` should be the one.

Answer (score 1):

Use following Colors for your widget. You will get OS specific background and foreground for your custom widget.

```
SWT.java
     * System color used to paint foreground areas (value is 21).
     */
    public static final int COLOR_WIDGET_FOREGROUND = 21;

    /**
     * System color used to paint background areas (value is 22).
     */
    public static final int COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND = 22;
```